# change dynamical values in rows angular

Tags: angularjs

Well I have a  problem when I change the values of a table but just need that change the value of the row, but this happen in all rows.

[image]
now if I change just a value, change all values of the right.

[image]
 in html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in detalleTransCover.details track by $index">
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="detail.plan_account_id" ng-options="planAcoount.id as (planAcoount.tipo_cuenta + ' -- ' + planAcoount.descripcion) for planAcoount in planAccounts"></select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.glosa" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.debeDolar" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.haberDolar" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.debeBolivianos" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.haberBolivianos" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="detail.cuentade" ng-change="subcuentasChange(detail.cuentade)">
                                            <option value="usuario">EMPLEADO</option>
                                            <option value="proveedor">PROVEEDOR</option>
                                            <!--<option value="cliente">CLIENTE</option>
                                            <option value="activo">ACTIVO FIJO</option>-->
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select class="form-control" ng-if="proveedorDropDown" ng-model="detail.plan_account_id" ng-options="proveedor.id as proveedor.razon_social for proveedor in proveedorDatos"></select>
                                        <select class="form-control" ng-if="userDropDown" ng-model="detail.plan_account_id" ng-options="user.id as user.name for user in userDatos"></select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

now in angular where i need that this happen have this:

```
$scope.userDropDown = false;
$scope.proveedorDropDown = false;
planaccountsfactory.getPlanAccounts().then(function (response) {
   $scope.planAccounts = response.data;
});
usersFactory.getUsers().then(function (response) {
    $scope.userDatos = response.data;
});
providersFactory.getProviders().then(function (response) {
    $scope.proveedorDatos = response.data;
});
$scope.subcuentasChange = function (type)
{
    if(type === 'usuario')
    {
        $scope.userDropDown = true;
        $scope.proveedorDropDown = false;
    }
    if(type === 'proveedor')
    {
        $scope.userDropDown = false;
        $scope.proveedorDropDown = true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.userDropDown = false;
$scope.proveedorDropDown = false;
```

These two variables are declared for all rows. You need to keep the value in each `detail` for each row.

I would change the function to something like this

```
$scope.subcuentasChange = function (detail)
{
    if(detail.type === 'usuario')
    {
        detail.userDropDown = true;
        detail.proveedorDropDown = false;
    }
    if(detail.type === 'proveedor')
    {
        detail.userDropDown = false;
        detail.proveedorDropDown = true;
    }
};
```

And pass `ng-change="subcuentasChange(detail)"` to function.
You can improve this by using separate array.

Also change ng-if correspondingly. I would keep only one flag like `isProvider` instead of two and use `ng-show="isProvider"` and `ng-hide="isProvider"` for selects.